# Install/Build graph-tool with python v3.6.0 (non-standard lib path)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, graph-tool

after now trying to build graph-tool for one day its time to ask for some help.

My problem: 
I dont get graph-tool installed for the right python version on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

As mentioned in the install guide: "sudo apt-get install python3-graph-tool" works great but for the wrong python version located in "/usr/bin/python3.5"

"which python3" returns "/usr/local/bin/python3.6" for which I want to install graph-tool. Since the apt-get isnt working I tried to build graph-tool from source but I always get: [Image: BuildError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx3WT.png)
"Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main python library has been installed in some non-standard library path..." YES!

So (as sugguested) I specified the LIBS with:

- ./configure PYTHON=python3 LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib"
- ./configure PYTHON=python3 LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib/python3.6"

But still getting the same error. The libs folders should be right: [Image: LibFolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAJOc.png)

Maybe a smart person knows what I am doing wrong? PLEASE help :)
Thanks in advance!